# Sending custom DHCP option to server with dhcpcd

Tags: dhcp

I've been trying for several days to configure dhcpcd to send a non-standard option to a DHCP server without any success. On the other hand dhclient works fine.

I need to send an option with code 90 which is a string specified in hex. The following dhclient configuration works fine :

```
option auth code 90 = string;
send auth 00:01:02:03...;
```

Yet I can't manage to do the same with dhcpcd. The manual quickly talks about custom options but it seems like those are for parsing DHCP replies and converting those custom options into shell variables then passed on to a shell script. What I'm looking for is to actually send a custom option to the server.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: If you can send options to a shell script, you are passing them to the server.  Right now all I see in your question is the context but not the actual problem.  What are you trying to do **exactly** that doesn't work?

Comment: @JuliePelletier I have an ISP which uses a non standard authentication option (it uses option 90 but is nothing like the standard option 90 as defined by the RFC) so I just need to send the hex value as the contents of the option 90. This works fine with dhclient, I'm trying to replicate this with dhcpcd as the latter is already integrated in my configuration management system and make things easier.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got almost the same problem. I want to send custom DHCP options from the client to the DHCP server (openWrt router). With wireshark I can see that the dhcp option is beeing send to the router, but i don't know how to receive and use the trasmitted custom date.